# How to change the conjunction word in citation call-outs?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

Does anyone know how to change the separator between author names when I cite them in the text? Let me explain better when I cite in the text the book it gives me as output "Karatzas `and` Shreve" but what I would like would be something like "Karatzas `e` Shreve". Basically I would like to replace the English word `and` with the Italian equivalent `e`. I see that there is the `\setcitestyle` command that accepts several parameters but none of them seems to give me a solution.

I leave the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{scrbook}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    hidelinks,   
    linktocpage=false,              
    colorlinks=true,  
    citecolor=NavyBlue,     
    linkcolor=NavyBlue,        
    urlcolor=NavyBlue,   
}

\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Wonderful Chapter}

As seen in \cite{ShreveKaratzas1991}

\bibliography{reference.bib}

\end{document}
```

and the `reference.bib` file

```
@book{ShreveKaratzas1991,
    edition = {2. ed},
    isbn = {0-387-97655-8},
    keywords = {Probabilità},
    language = {eng},
    publisher = {Springer},
    series = {Graduate texts in mathematics},
    title = {Brownian motion and stochastic calculus},
    year = {1991},
    author = {Karatzas, Ioannis and Shreve, Steven E.},
    address = {New York},
    booktitle = {Brownian motion and stochastic calculus},
}
```

Thank you to anyone who wants to help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to start using Biblatex instead. Then it will use the language the text is in (if you state that for example by using the Babel package). Here is an example, where I haven't tried to exactly mimic what you currently have, but I did include a setting to use square parentheses, since you have that.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Wonderful Chapter}

As seen in \citet{ShreveKaratzas1991}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This will yield "Karatzas e Shreve [1991]".

Comment: It does not work well in my long document anyway I find a way to fix using your code so thank you :)

Comment: However the problem is that when it prints the cross reference with `hyperref` only the publication year link is clickable and not the entire citation. For this reason I left in the MWE also the hyperref package however I am being satisfied thank you again :)